# after sending few emails Could not connect to SMTP host , nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I want to get all unread emails from server and send each message to another email. When I send each unread email (Using HostGator), after sending few mails (30-40) an error occurs as I mentioned. This is my sending method. What can i do? I checked with smtp port 25,465,587. but none of them worked. Same error appears. :/ if any one knows how to handle it please let me know. Thank you..

email send method:-

```
public static void send(String sub,final String user, final String pass, String toMails) throws Exception {   
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "gator.hostgator.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
        }
    });
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toMails);

    message.setSubject(sub);
    message.setText("-Body-");

    BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart1.setText("-Body-");      

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);    
    message.setContent(multipart);  
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

This is error message :-[image]

Comment: The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide more clues, but it could be that you're connecting too frequently and the server is refusing your connections to slow you down.  See also these [JavaMail connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: Thanks Bill Shannon :) Yes, I am sending emails through a loop. As you said I slow down the loop using thread. But same error appears after few mails.

Comment: Try using a [single Transport object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#rptsend).  If that doesn't help you'll need to talk to your server vendor to understand what you're doing that violates their terms of service and causes them to refuse your connections.